# Mysql function to return row count from a procedure call

Tags: mysql, function, count, procedure

I am trying to write a function to return the number of rows a call to a stored procedure would return. I'm trying to minimise repetition of the code (for reduced code maintenance/debugging- the procedure select is long).

The stored procedure just read-only selects rows matching certain criteria (vague I know but details should not be material to the question).

I could just copy the procedure into a function and change the select to count() but as it is long with multiple joins I was hoping to write a function that could call the procedure and return the row count. The goal is not for optimised running but for efficient code maintenance, boiler plate reduction.

I have tried this as a test:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS proc_select1()
BEGIN
    SELECT 1;
END //

CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS select1_count() RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
BEGIN
    CALL proc_select1();
    RETURN FOUND_ROWS();
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

However when I `SELECT select1_count();` - which I am hoping will return `1` - I get the "cannot return a result set from a function" error.

I tried assigning `FOUND_ROWS` to a variable, clearing the result set then returning the variable value but can't get it to work.

Does anyone know a work around or do I really need to copy-paste the procedure and convert to a `SELECT COUNT` and function?

I'm using MySQL 5.5.16 (can upgrade if necessary), Windows 7 (nobody seems to want to upgrade :) with HeidiSQLv7.0.0.4053 (if relevant)

As always, any help much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you storing the result from `proc_select1()`  and how `FOUND_ROWS()` will be using it ?

Comment: @Meherzad I don't need to store the results from proc_select1() - I only need the count. As I understand it `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the row count of the last select statement ie from the procdure call in the case of the `select1_count()` function. It just seems that mysql doesn't like the fact there is a result set in the function ie it can't guarantee db state unchanged. I guess I'm just hunting if any genius out there knows a clever workaround. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: CREATE PROCEDURE IF NOT EXISTS is not proper mysql syntax. Same with FUNCTION. Don't you mean: DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc; CREATE PROCEDURE proc(...

Answer (score 0):

first use distinct to get distinct values then use count on that..like

`select count(distinct column_name) from table_name`

Comment: i dont know about procedure call but i think this can help u

Comment: Thanks. It's not so much the form of the count- I have the select statement all worked out and currently under testing. I could just change the `SELECT columns... FROM` to `SELECT count (* FROM` with or without `DISTINCT` depending on what I needed to pull back. I'm trying more to not have to copy-paste the select statement to make the function as its very long. Thanks for looking at this tough.

Comment: i cant properly understand what u r looking for but u can use a count variable which will return number of rows count or if u dont want to use distinct then u can use Union as well....ignore if not helpful..thanx

Answer (score 0):

> cannot return a result set from a function

This error happens when a `SELECT` query is done in a procedure without storing the output values.
Other thing : don't forget to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to indicates your DBMS to store the number of found rows.

I tried to make it work without any temporary variable (Maybe there is exists a mysql keyword to not "return" the set of the `SELECT` query), but no success. Here a piece of code which works using temporary var.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE  proc_select1()
BEGIN
    DECLARE temp INT;
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 1 INTO temp;   
END //

CREATE FUNCTION select1_count() RETURNS INT UNSIGNED
BEGIN
    CALL proc_select1();
    RETURN FOUND_ROWS();
END //
```

The result is 1 as expected :-) cf : [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/261d2/1)

Comment: Thanks @Marcassin. I also tried a `FLUSH QUERY CACHE` in the procedure and/or in the function as a test to see if that avoids the error. It clearly isn't good coding and didn't work anyway. So it seems as though this is not possible and I will have to copy-paste the `SELECT`, change the rows pulled back to a `COUNT()` and then (hope to remember to) replicate any changes made in the procedure to the function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is not possible. The select statement is required to `SELECT INTO` something to avoid the `cannot return a result set from a function` error during the function call. If this is not possible or required in the `SELECT` statement used in the procedure then the function will not run without error.

Using `CLEAR QUERY CACHE` or `FLUSH QUERY CACHE` after the procedure call did not help (and is probably a bad idea / bad coding anyway).